# How to render polymorphic list in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymorphism, vuejs2

Consider:

```
class X {}
class B extends X {}
class C extends X {}
```

In a component, I have an array of X:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items">
            <a-view v-if="item.constructor.name === 'A'"></a-view>
            <b-view v-if="item.constructor.name === 'B'"></b-view>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

export default {
    ...
data() {
    return {
        items: [new A(), new B()]
    }
}
```

This works, but is not elegant. The typecheck uses a string, where `item instanceof B` would be idiomatic es6 code. However, this does not work.

What is the idiomatic way of rendering a polymorphic list in vue.js?

Answer (score 6):

`Component` keyword must be what you are looking for, like this:

```
<li v-for="item in items">
  <component v-bind:is="item"></component>
<li>
```

[Reference from Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/k2mwrj6w3r

Comment: The docs are pretty confusing to me. I tried your solution using `<component v-bind:is="B"></component>` but this does not work.

Comment: @Ruudjah it should be not "B", but "item" as I wrote above. It will render the component that is referred. In your for loop example, it will first render A component, then B component.

Comment: @Ruudjah I added an example code to the answer. Look at App.vue, ComponentA.vue and ComponentB.vue. Hope it helps.

Comment: @cmertayak Perfect!